# dynamic container hostname injection to application properties and /etc/hosts

Tags: kubernetes, containers, rancher

I am trying to create a deployment of 3 replicas of containers of the same image.
Each of container would require to include the unique hostname in two places:

1. /etc/hosts or resolvable by a dns
2. an application properties file and cmd line
   However, the hostname is not known until after container is started and even it's started, I found that I can ping ip of another container in one container but NOT the container name.

I understand that I can write a script to update but is there a more generic way to get this done. This is not an uncommon task/requirement.

Thanks.

Comment: Replicas (pods) of a Deployment use identical PodTemplates

Comment: Hi @Jonas understood. but the hostname and ip won't be unknown until pod is started as far as how my test goes.  Is there a way to pre set pod name and ip during configuration?

Comment: @Jin Ma your issue got resolved?

Comment: Not fully resolved.